# Angular concat 2 expressions

Tags: html, angular, concatenation

I got this:
`{{columns.field}}` and this `{{resultado.!!!}}`
and inside the !!! I need to put the `{{columns.field}}` I can't find a way to do it
I need to do it like this because I don't know the field in !!!, for that reason I got the `{{columns.field}}`, in this expression I picked up the value I need to put in !!!. 
I'm sorry for my bad way of expressing myself
[I tried something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXqt2.png)

Comment: Can you add the json to to question ?

Comment: Yes post the json then we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ready for top level Javascript ?

```
{{resultado[columns.field]}}
```